# Empty search result when trying to create PHP search script

Tags: php, mysql

why when i try to search mysql database, it shows 0 result? i altered the table into FULLTEXT etc properly. What am I missing? I have put the very basic search exercise code down here. I want to  search into my table 'products' and extract the details from there. but no luck

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$search_output = "";
if(isset($_POST['searchquery']) && $_POST['searchquery'] != ""){
    $searchquery = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!]#i', '', $_POST['searchquery']);
    if($_POST['filter1'] == "Whole Site"){
        $sqlCommand = "SELECT product_name AS name, details AS details FROM products WHERE MATCH (product_name ,details) AGAINST ('$searchquery' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
    } 
    require_once("storescripts/connect_to_mysqli.php");
    $query = mysqli_query($myConnection,$sqlCommand) or die(mysqli_error($myConnection));
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($count > 1){
        $search_output .= "<hr />$count results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />$sqlCommand<hr />";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

            $name = $row["name"];
                    $details= $row["details"];
            $search_output .= "Name: '.$name.' - '.$details.'<br />";
        } // close while
    } else {
        $search_output = "<hr />0 results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />$sqlCommand";
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Search the Exercise Tables</h2>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
Search For: 
  <input name="searchquery" type="text" size="44" maxlength="88"> 
Within: 
<select name="filter1">
<option value="Whole Site">Whole Site</option>

</select>
<input name="myBtn" type="submit">
<br />
</form>
<div>
<?php echo $search_output; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
$sqlCommand = "SELECT product_name AS name, details AS details FROM products WHERE MATCH (product_name ,details) AGAINST ('".$searchquery."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

i have changed

```
AGAINST ('$searchquery' IN
```

to

```
AGAINST ('".$searchquery."' IN
```

Comment: guess what, i have tried here and there for the whole day and you make my day...it works =D

I not sure why '$searchquery' but '".$searchquery."' works...

Comment: it would be awesome if you tell why approach in your answer is working and why OP's not working

Comment: its because you need single quotes around the string in SQL

Comment: it don't have nothing with sql, we are still in php, so to execute what he need ,the String must have the value of $searchquery that must be wroten like I did, else if he leave like he did it will work also but for sql the word to search is  '$searchquery', what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Problem is there with your if part as:

1. replace your current :

   `if($_POST['filter1'] == "Whole Site")
    {
    $sqlCommand = "SELECT product_name AS name, details AS details FROM products WHERE MATCH        (product_name ,details) AGAINST ({$searchquery} IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
     }`
2. In case it couldnt get to query due to if statement add:

   `else {
     echo "No seqrch query found";
    }`

hope it works now

Comment: it would be awesome if you tell why approach in your answer is working and why OP's not working

Comment: its simple as php takes single quoted variable as a string not a variable anymore so at time of search it wont be replaced by the value itself. So here i used curly braces as Any scalar variable, array element or object property with a string representation can be included via this syntax. Simply write the expression the same way as it would appear outside the string, and then wrap it in { and }. Since { can not be escaped, this syntax will only be recognised when the $ immediately follows the {. Use {\$ to get a literal {$.